# How to parse sub elements in lxml via xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

```
page = urlopen(req)
doc = parse(page).getroot()
table = doc.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/table')
table
<Element table ...>
doc.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/table/tr')
<Element tr ...>...
table.xpath('/tr')
[]
```

Why doesn't `table.xpath('/tr')` produce the same list of elements `doc.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/table/tr')` does?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but try `table.xpath('./tr')` or '//tr'.

Comment: What's the purpose? for instance - web scraping or just something else?

Comment: web scraping yes, why do you think it is overkill?

Comment: please just put that in either a tag or title!?

Comment: it was just an example. I'm trying to learn xpath and lxml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because an xpath starting with `/` always starts matching at the document root.

To avoid this, either leave the slash out, or be explicit and use `.` to match the current element.
Either of these should work:

```
table.xpath('tr')
# or
table.xpath('./tr')
```